# Hide parent span if child is empty

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a whole span if a child span is empty.

I've got the following HTML structure:

```
<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 1</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper">
        Content 1
        Content 1
        Content 1
    </span>
</span>

<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 2</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper">

    </span>
</span>

<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 3</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper">
        Content 3
        Content 3
        Content 3
    </span>
</span>
```

In the instance of the empty `training-vessels-wrapper`, I want to hide it's parent `training-crew-wrapper`. I've got the following JQuery:

```
$('.training-crew-wrapper').each(function() {

    $length = $(this).find( ".training-vessels-wrapper" ).text().replace(/\s/g,'').length;

    if ( $length == 0 ) {
        $( ".training-crew-wrapper" ).empty();
    }

});
```

Unfortunately my JQuery seems to just empty all instances of `training-crew-wrapper`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use `$( this ).empty();` because `$( ".training-crew-wrapper" )` refers to all instances

Answer (score 0):

I Hope You are trying to do like this

```js
$('.training-crew-wrapper').each(function() {
      var htmlstring = $(this).find( ".training-vessels-wrapper" ).html();
      htmlstring = (htmlstring.trim) ? htmlstring.trim() : htmlstring.replace(/^\s+/,''); 
      if(htmlstring == ''){
        $(this).find( ".training-vessels-wrapper" ).parent().remove();
      } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 1</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper">
        Content 1
        Content 1
        Content 1
    </span>
</span>

<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 2</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper"> 
    </span>
</span>

<span class="training-crew-wrapper">
    <h5>Title 3</h5>
    <span class="training-vessels-wrapper">
        Content 3
        Content 3
        Content 3
    </span>
</span>
```

[My CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/udarakasun/pen/qBBVNbV)